# Visual Stuidio Plugin Material Icon Theme4.5.0 isnt working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

**My Problem** #0.1
[Check the SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEU7s.jpg)

As you can see in the picture I already install the plugin and it's enabled, and in the left side of the picture you can see nothing is applied on my files, But it works fine when I'm uninstalling and reinstall again and when I close the visual studio and open it again it's not working.

I tried to make it a default for the visual studio but I didn't see any option in settings like that.

What should I do now? I want to use it default for every next time. I don't want to uninstall and install it again and again.

Comment: is it possible you forgot to attach a screenshot to your question?

Comment: My bad it was my first question, I'm not familiar with it, just trying now its ok please check the SS from the link.